# I would like to display text when I press a button

Tags: html, button

I would like to know how to put a button on my code and when I click it, it displays text.

For example: when I click it and it should say thank you.

how I can put this in code form?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes but i looked for 10 minutes and i still can't find the answer can you please help me

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: also the website made me fix my question so i couldn't answer you right away. sorry

Comment: ok i will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a code based on what I understood from your question

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <button id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</button>
  <script>
   function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "thank you!";
    }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```